# Filtering datalist by onchange from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I beginner on javascript

I have select component that contains list of class and input that contains datalist `name` from table in mysql

here my simple code :

```
<select class="form-control" name="class" id="class" onchange="" value="--">
    <option>--</option>
    <option>X NET 1</option>
    <option>X NET 2</option>
    <option>XI NET 1</option>
    <option>XI NET 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" list="checkName" autocomplete="off" required>
<datalist id="checkName">
    <?php
        $sql_siswa = "SELECT name,class from student order by name;";
        $result = $conn->query($sql_siswa);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<option value=\"".$row["name"]."\">";
            }
        }
    ?>
</datalist>
```

so, I want if I select class, datalist will retrieve name student by class from filter by php.
here filtering like this:

```
$sql_siswa = "SELECT name from student where class like '".$_POST["class"]."' order by name;";
$result = $conn->query($sql_siswa);
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<option value=\"".$row["name"]."\">";
    }
}
```

how to implement this filter in `onchange`?
I'm sorry, I have not try anything because I have no idea what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try ajax to do that

```
<select class="form-control" name="class" id="class" onchange="ajax_change(this.value)" >
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="X NET 1">X NET 1</option>
<option value="X NET 2">X NET 2</option>
<option value="XI NET 1">XI NET 1</option>
<option value="XI NET 2">XI NET 2</option>
</select>
```

In your script

```
function ajax_change(str){
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {class: str},
        success: function (data) {            
           $("#checkName").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
           //Do Something to handle error
           alert("some error found");
        }
    });
 }
```

In your ajax.php

```
//include connection
if(isset($_POST["class"])){
$sql_siswa = "SELECT name from student where class like '".$_POST["class"]."' order by name;";
$result = $conn->query($sql_siswa);
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<option value=\"".$row["name"]."\">";
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's great.

Comment: glad to hear that